# Any way to find the component starting from a DOM element in Lightning Components?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am using a 3rd party library that passes around DOM elements and am faced with a circumstance where I need to find the component of the containing DOM element to make a `$A.createComponent` call.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having tried a bunch of crazy things, this appears to be a straightforward approach...

Add the global Id to the root DOM element that you want to get the component for:

```
<aura:component>
    ...
    <span data-global-id="{! globalId }">
        ...
    </span>
</aura:component>
```

Then in the relevant controller use (the not very frequently mentioned) [$A.getComponent](http://documentation.auraframework.org/auradocs#reference?topic=api:$A):

```
var globalId = el.getAttribute('data-global-id');
var c = $A.getComponent(globalId);
```